# GLM for proportion data in r

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, stata, proportion

I have proportion data on the percentage of female employees in 500 organizations. I want to use GLM to explain this dependent variable using other independent variables such as company size, industry, etc. I used a GLM regression in Stata as recommended [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/faq/how-does-one-do-regression-when-the-dependent-variable-is-a-proportion/).

The stata model looks like this:

```
glm PercentageFemale othervariables, link(logit) family(binomial) robust nolog
```

However, when I try to replicate my results in R I get different results. My model in R looks like this:

```
fitglm <- glm (formula = cbind(Successes, Failures) ~ other variables, family = binomial)
```

Where `successes` is the number of females in the company and `failures` the number of men. I know I can't use the percentage directly in R as I did in Stata, so I used `cbind`. I tried using `glmrobust` but an error saying the system is exactly singular occurs.

Any ideas on how I can replicate my Stata results in R? Am I doing something wrong when I use `cbind` in R?

Comment: The use of `cbind` looks correct, the problem lies elsewhere. `Exact singular` points to collinearity, so check your model formula and covariables.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Stata command will show error because the `glm` statement used specifies a logistic regression with 1/0 as outcome. You should see an error message "*note: PercentageFemale has noninteger values.*" However, your R command is correctly specified.

Since you didn't provide data, let's start with a replicable example in R:

```
library(MASS)
data(menarche)
out <- glm(cbind(Menarche, Total-Menarche) ~ Age,
           family=binomial(logit), data=menarche)
summary(out)

# Export into Stata data
library(foreign)
write.dta(menarche, "c:\\temp\\menarche.dta")
```

And the outcome is:

```
[PRINTOUT SNIPPED FOR SPACE]

    Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -21.22639    0.77068  -27.54   <2e-16 ***
Age           1.63197    0.05895   27.68   <2e-16 ***
---

[PRINTOUT SNIPPED FOR SPACE]
```

Now, to replicate that in Stata. First let's get the error:

```
gen pm = Menarche / Total
glm pm Age, link(logit) family(binomial)
```

Results:

```
. glm pm Age, link(logit) family(binomial)
note: pm has noninteger values  

[SNIPPED FOR SPACE]   
                                                   AIC             =  .5990425
Log likelihood   = -5.488031242                    BIC             = -73.81271

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |                 OIM
          pm |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         Age |   1.608169   .6215021     2.59   0.010      .390047    2.826291
       _cons |  -20.91168   8.111063    -2.58   0.010    -36.80907   -5.014291
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The results do not agree. And also notice the error message on line 2.

To make Stata talk to the format of your data set, use `blogit`. Notice that while in R, it's the number of yes and number of no; in Stata, it's the number of yes followed by the number of total:

```
blogit Menarche Total Age
```

Here are the results that go with R:

```
Logistic regression for grouped data              Number of obs   =       3918
                                                  LR chi2(1)      =    3667.18
                                                  Prob > chi2     =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -819.65237                       Pseudo R2       =     0.6911

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    _outcome |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         Age |   1.631968   .0589532    27.68   0.000     1.516422    1.747514
       _cons |  -21.22639   .7706859   -27.54   0.000    -22.73691   -19.71588
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I disregarded the error message in Stata because I read somewhere that GLM in stata was now able to handle percentages directly, I'm guessing this information was wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey Penguin, I noticed that in the example provided by IDRE (http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/faq/proportion.htm) the same error message that you mentioned occurs. Could this error (actually a "note") be less bad then?