# Count data on proportion or different kind of type?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I really do not know which kind of variable my response data is. I cannot find any answer to my question in the world wide web.

I have the results from a survey of 900 consumer. Each consumer told on how many m² he used one cleaning agent. So the result can be maybe 0.11 = They used a cleaning agent on 11% of their house or 1= Use on 100% of house. I guess its count data on proportion, but I am not sure, because i did not find any similar example.

The distribution of the data is shown below (there are also many farmers who used on 0% of their fields a pesticide:

I need to know it, because i try to do an analysis of my data with a Generalized linear model in R (with poisson,binomial or gamma errors).

It is necessary to know if it is count data on proportion or something else.

What would you guess is it continuous data or count data on proportion or something else?

Comment: "11% of a field" is a continuous proportion, not a count proportion.

Comment: So, do you think a beta regression fits better or a glm model (binomial), like in the following example ? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89734/glm-for-proportion-data-in-r?rq=1

Comment: What 'fits better' depends on the data set. But I'd use the beta for this problem, since you have a continuous proportion and I have no reason to expect the binomial variance function to apply to it.

Comment: Thanks!! My research resulted in working with the gamlss-package (BEINF). Cause i have a zero and one inflated beta regression. 
I have four predictors about farm characteristics (farm size in hectares, crop rotation-Index (0-2,08), goodness of the soil (points from 7 till 100), and the part of the farm which was plowed in percent (0-1) (including ones and zeroes)). 
So far so good, the model-plot looks fine, erorrs are normally distributed. But i didnt specified the distribution parameters "mu", "sigma", "nu" or "tau". Do you know if this is necessary?

Comment: I haven't used `BEINF` family objects in `gamlss`, only `betareg` in package [`betareg`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/vignettes/betareg.pdf) (and then only some time ago).

Answer (score 4):

Note that although you're counting how many farmers give each response, the response itself isn't a count, it's a proportion. For a response that is a proportion, the usual family of distributions with support on [0, 1] is the beta distribution. If you're having trouble accounting for all the 0% and 100% responses, your data may follow a zero-one-inflated beta distribution.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me alot! I just read some articles about beta regressions. There are beta regressions, and beta regressions inflated with 0 and/or 1´s.             In my data are three response-variables, like shown above in the histogram. They have got between 266 and 400 zeroes and between 1 and 12 one´s (n=865). Is this then called zero-and-one inflated or just zero-inflated data? Maybe the ones are not the problem, and if, i could change them to 0.99 to calculate with zero-inflated beta models?